# Add field to django auth user?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a new field to the built in auth user. Here is my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    newField = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=16))

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And in my view I have the following:

```
current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
current_user.save()
```

And i am getting the error

```
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value: User has no profile.
```

Am i doing this wrong? I creates a profile table in the db but that didnt seem to be the issue

Comment: Have you added Profile in models.py after creating the user?

Answer (score 1):

Its maybe because you are creating user and triggering both signal functions at a time. So maybe you can try like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def save_user_profile(sender, instance,  created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        instance.profile.save()
```

Or better,combine both signals into one:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your are defining two signals with one sender. So when the user is saved, both signals will be triggered, But the second is faster and will execute right away. And because for that user no `profile` is created, it throws an error. Because the `profile` object for that user by first signal isn't created yet.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**Note** no need to perform `instance.profile.save()` here.